# What is meant by the $sl(N)$ colored jones function?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3147, Hugh Morton and other authors discuss the $sl(3)$ colored Jones polynomial. It was my understanding that $sl(N)$ gives rise to the colored HOMFLY polynomials and that it was $SU(2)$ gives rise to the colored Jones Polynomial.... Can somebody explain this discrepancy for me? Thank you.

Also, any references for an introduction to the colored Jones polynomial are appreciated

Comment: But then why is there only one indeterminate??

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I guess it's a specialization of the HOMFLY polynomial. The variables are both taken to be specific polynomials in $q$ (which polynomials depends on your conventions for the HOMFLY polynomial), see e.g.: http://www.jointmathematicsmeetings.org/tran/2010-362-01/S0002-9947-09-04691-1/S0002-9947-09-04691-1.pdf

Comment: The Jones polynomial can also be viewed as coming from $\mathfrak{sl}_2$

Comment: Really???? do you mean the quantum universal enveloping algebra of $sl2$?